# Django correct url path but got page not found url didn't match

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm having a hard time with this error and I'm not sure how to fix it

I have this in my `urls.py`

```
  path('service/author/<uuid:author_id>/followers/', views.get_followers),
  path('service/author/<uuid:author_id>/followers/<uuid:foreign_author_id>/', views.edit_followers),
```

the first path work when I go to it, but the second path will always give me 404 page not

> Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
> ...
> service/author/uuid:author_id/followers/
> service/author/uuid:author_id/followers/uuid:foreign_author_id/
> ...
> The current path, service/author/075194d3-6885-417e-a8a8-6c931e272f00/followers/089200d3-6885-417e-v0v0-6c555f272f00, didn't match any of these.

but it will work when I go to the same path but without the second uuid: service/author/075194d3-6885-417e-a8a8-6c931e272f00/followers/

I would really appreciate any help or insight into this issue, thank you!

Comment: You're missing a trailing slash in your request URL

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I realized that the uuid that I typed in is not an actual uuid (089200d3-6885-417e-v0v0-6c555f272f00). That's why when django convert it, it doesn't match with my defined path.
So when I type in a path with two correct uuids it works just fine. For example: /service/author/da22bbe6-68b4-4a1d-b5ff-e063dfd5934b/followers/d3dfca14-bd6d-4f53-a148-e90fcd24c4ab